# How to convert country names from English to French with the countrycode package?

Tags: r

How can one translate country names (for example, from English to French) with the `countrycode()` package?

Comment: Well, from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/countrycode/countrycode.pdf), it seems that you can only convert country names into country code, e.g. with `countrycodes <- countrycode(countrynames, "country.name", "iso3c"`).

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was possible, but I am note sure, with this article "https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode". With this example for just one single country : # German to French
countrycode('Albanien', 'country.name.de', 'country.name.fr') 
[1] "Albanie"

Comment: Well, then try to use it with `countrycode(yourvector, 'country.name.en', 'country.name.fr')`.

Comment: @chc please accept the response by cjyetman. This feature is now available on CRAN as of version 0.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to French country names is a feature (one of many) that was recently added to the `countrycode` package, and is in the [currently available version (0.19) on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=countrycode)

with version 0.19 or higher installed and loaded, you can convert to French country names with a command like...

`countrycode(c('Germany', 'USA'), 'country.name', 'country.name.fr')`

which will return...

`[1] "Allemagne"             "États-Unis d'Amérique"`

---

**Update 2021.08.23**

(thanks to Samuel Calderon in the comments below)

as of v1.3.0, the proper syntax/destination code is:

`countrycode(c('Germany', 'USA'), 'country.name', 'cldr.name.fr')`

Comment: this feature is now available on CRAN in version 0.19

Comment: Just to say that currently, with v 1.3.0, the code changed to `countrycode(c('Germany', 'USA'), 'country.name', 'cldr.name.fr')`